# Kali linux Не работает wifi адаптер

Tags: wifi, wsl, microsoft-store

Я скачал **kali linux** Через **microsoft store** так же у меня есть **usb wifi адаптер** На винде он работает пытаюсь запустить адаптер **Kali linux** и он его не видит

Comment: А смысл ставить Kali Linux через microsoft store?

Answer (score 1):

Он и не будет его видеть, так как в WSL нет поддержки аппаратной части, т.е. видеть может и увидит, но взаимодействие ложится на головную систему, т.е. 10ку.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, поддерживает ли ваш чипсет kali. Если да, то установите драйвер. Но это не факт, что он будет поддерживать функцию мониторинга.  Лучше купите Alfa.

Comment: Kali внутри винды, WSLу запрещено взаимодействовать с аппаратной частью.